# Bootstrap-5 drop-down not working and always shows popper CSS "margin" styles cannot be used

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap 5.2 in my project and I'm getting the below error when I click dropdown option in the nav-bar. I'm using Bootstrap [offcanvas-navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/offcanvas-navbar/).

```
Popper: CSS "margin" styles cannot be used to apply padding between the popper and its reference element or boundary. To replicate margin, use the `offset` modifier, as well as the `padding` option in the `preventOverflow` and `flip` modifiers.
```

I have tried most of the possible solutions that are uploaded to the internet, but unfortunately it didb't help.

The main.js file is:

```js
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

import jquery from 'jquery';

window.Alpine = Alpine;
window.$ = jquery;
window.jQuery = jquery;

import '@popperjs/core/dist/umd/popper.min.js';

import 'daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css';
import 'diff2html/bundles/css/diff2html.min.css';
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css';

import './main.css';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js';


window.$(() => {
....
});
```

The main.css file is:

```css
/*-offcanvas-start-*/
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
  .offcanvas-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
    bottom: 0;
    left: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    visibility: hidden;
    background-color: #343a40;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
  }
  .offcanvas-collapse.open {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
}

.nav-scroller .nav-link {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  color: #6c757d;
}

.nav-scroller .nav-link:hover {
  color: #007bff;
}

.nav-scroller .active {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #343a40;
}

.bg-purple {
  background-color: #6f42c1;
}

.bd-placeholder-img {
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  text-anchor: middle;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}

.b-example-divider {
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-width: 1px 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
}

.b-example-vr {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 1.5rem;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bi {
  vertical-align: -.125em;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

/*-offcanvas-end-*/
```

My html file is:

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <link href="/resources/icons/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" />
      <link href="/assets/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" name="viewport" />
    </head>
    <body class="bg-light">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Dashboard</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
              <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row flex-xl-nowrap">
          <main class="py-md-3 pl-md-5 bd-content" role="main">
            coming soon
          </main>
        </div>
      </div>
      <footer class="container-fluid text-end p-3"></footer>
      <script src="/assets/main.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

What I'm doing wrong?, Can someone help me please?

Comment: Note that Bootstrap.bundle.js already includes popper.js.  So you may not want to load it independently (twice) as in your code. See "bundle" heading in: [Bootstrap 5 Introduction](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: I have removed the import of popper, still dropdown is not working and getting the same error. –

Comment: @kiran have you found any solution?